# Altium: how to disable Messages dialog when jumping to component

Tags: altium

When I use Jump Component (shortcut j-c) and enter a designator, the Messages dialog pops up with a history of recently searched designators. Is there a way to prevent the dialog from showing when I use Jump Component?

Comment: There's definitely a way, mine doesn't do that but I don't know what I did to prevent it

Comment: I have the Messages pane docked on the left with Projects, etc. So although JC causes the Messages pane to become active it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: @SteveG, Doesn't work for me unfortunately -  the dialog still shows up.

Comment: @pavel So it's a dialog? Not the messages panel?

Comment: @DerStrom8, apologies, I meant the messages panel. If I dock it, it still shows when I use Jump Component.

Comment: Steve wasn't saying they stopped showing up, he said it wouldn't pop up right in front of you (it would be docked and wouldn't get in the way)

Comment: That's exactly what it does, unfortunately. In fact it takes up almost the entire screen when it's docked. It goes away after 2 sec but it's still frustrating until it does.

Comment: I have un-docked the message pannel and moved it to to my second or third screen. There it can pop-up and show whatever it likes and does not disturb me anymore.